# CodeAcademy: Loops and Arrays 2, 12/14

Tags: javascript

I'm currently on the above excercise ^. I've basically got to try and get the five names printed out along with the string in the console.log below and for some reason I can't get this to work at all:

```
var names = ["Tobias", "Jehovah", "Jake", "Joseph", "Damn"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + [i])
}
```

Instead of printing out the names it prints out "I know someone called 1." I know this is really simple and I'm going to feel an idiot for it but I appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = ["Tobias", "Jehovah", "Jake", "Joseph", "Damn"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the array

```
names[i]
```

`i` is the index inside the `for` loop, so you put the array variable name, followed by the index to get the name at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `names` array.

```
var names = ["Tobias", "Jehovah", "Jake", "Joseph", "Damn"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])
}
```

Some informations about array: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

`[i]` is an array literal of an array that contains one item. To access an array (or object property), you use the `[n]` syntax, but you do it after the object name: `names[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

i is just an increasing number.

```
var names = ["Tobias", "Jehovah", "Jake", "Joseph", "Damn"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])
 }
```

should do

Your for - loop has no chance to get to the names. 
with your variable names[i], you are accessing the i-th element of the names array.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out [i] when you should be printing out names[i].

```
var names = ["Tobias", "Jehovah", "Jake", "Joseph", "Damn"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the space between called and the name. This should work:

```
var names = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
console.log("I know someone called"+" "+names[i]);
}
```

=)